# Openvpn authenticating to multiple AD domains

Tags: active-directory, openvpn

I've a site with openvpn server on linux authenticating users against Active Directory (domain A) everything working fine.

Now company has a different AD domain (B) with "Trust" setuped to original domain A.

Is there a simple way to 
a) have users from domain B to appear in domain A?
b) tweak a openvpn to try multiple AD domains?

I can simply setup another openvpn instance on another port but I'd like to have one configuration for all users.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenVPN LDAP plug-in doesn't appear to have functionality to support multiple LDAP servers (at least, that I'm seeing).

If you wanted to stick w/ stock Windows functionality you could deploy [Network Policy Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771347.aspx), Microsoft's RADIUS server, and use it to authenticate users in both domains.

You could also deploy an LDAP proxy to sit between the two AD domains and the OpenVPN server.

I'd go the RADIUS route, personally, because it abstracts away the LDAP and trust relationships very conveniently.